# How to fix 'Syntax error Unexpected identifier' error page displayed using nuxt for vue ssr

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to run a nuxt application in development mode on a system running windows 8.1 OS 64bit.

After I cloned from my online repository. I installed all dependencies with *npm install*. It was successful, then I proceed to startup the development server using *npm run dev* from the terminal, it compiles successfully and display server listening on http://localhost:3000.

When I navigates to the *http://localhost:3000* through my browser, this message is displayed "syntax error unexpected identifier" pointing to a vm.js

Comment: I later found a solution that works for me. Check below

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/nuxt/create-nuxt-app/246/496239643